# geom format in postGIS use to print in google maps android

Tags: postgresql, google-maps-android-api-2, postgis

a greeting, a friend happened to me a route of transportation and I step in the following format:

```
0102000020E610000049020000F2D077B7B23A53C0F03504C7651428C07E703E75AC3A53C07E37DDB2431428C07E8AE3C...
```

He told me it was a `MultiLineString`. I used the `PostGIS` function:

```
SELECT St_asewkt ('0102000020E6100000810200 .....');
```

with this i supposedly should be able to get the `wkt` format that I can 
get the coordinates and use it on google maps api to paint a path in android, but when using it throws me empty. Help me please

I need to get something like `MULTILINESTRING((0 0,1 1,1 2),(2 3,3 2,5 4))  ...` to get lat lng coordinates to paint it in google maps api with android.

To summarize what I have is this value

`0102000020E6100000810200 .....` and would like to paint it in android with google maps api, that's why I try to get the coordinates that function.

Comment: try [ST_AsText](http://www.postgis.org/docs/ST_AsText.html)

Comment: The result is empty :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you  have is [Well know binary, WKB](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Well-known_text), which is explained on this page along with its companion well known text (WKT), but in an ASCII (hex) representation, see [the docs](http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.0/using_postgis_dbmanagement.html#EWKB_EWKT)

If you do something like:

```
select st_setsrid(st_makepoint(50, -2),4326);
```

you will see `0101000020E6100000000000000000494000000000000000C0`, similar to what you have.

You can insert these directly into a db with

```
create table test (g geometry);
insert into test(g) values(ST_GeomFromEWKB(E'\\x0101000020E6100000000000000000494000000000000000C0')
```

where the `E'\\x` indicates that you are inserted a hex string, see [binary format docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/datatype-binary.html).

If you now do

```
select g from test;
```

you will get your WKB back and if you do

```
select st_astext(g) from test;
```

you will see the more human-readable WKT format.

The best way to load data in the correct format is to use:

```
 COPY table_name FROM your_file.csv CSV;
```

where your wkb would be, as is, unquoted, in the your_file.csv.

Comment: a very good contribution, I think if the solution but for some reason not working. It is inserted correctly but the data show, shows empty. 

you think that's wrong? My friend told me that was the rid is 4326

Comment: if you want I can send you full value for you to try, maybe I'm wrong

Comment: I have like 20 such routes and none work for me. has 16410 digits format and start as 0102000020E610000000020000ED17951D064853C03CFA1A4281F827C01F...

Comment: seems it does not support very long lengths, help pls.

Comment: The hex-encoded WKB can also be treated as a regular string too, which is why `SELECT '0101000020E6100000000000000000494000000000000000C0'::geometry` works.